# Is there a standard for distributing permission for account creation?

Tags: login, password, signup-signon, accounts

I am creating a web app that will require the user to have an account to access, but I am not allowing people to create accounts freely. I want to give specific people permission to a pre-existing account. Is there a common/standard way of doing this that is user friendly and secure? For example, taking the person's email and emailing them a link to a page that they can create a user name and password for their account on?

It's a video upload service and I have the contact information of people that need to be given log in capabilities already.

Comment: What type of service are you creating? What is the reason for not allowing accounts to be created?

Comment: If it is exclusive... You can email out a link to register with a one time token...

Comment: How do people find your site? Through you or through the web? If through the web, a "request invite" may be appropriate.

Comment: People don't find the site, I tell them about it in person or by email (I already have contact information), and then give them log in capabilities.

Comment: It's a video upload service. Emailing a link to register sounds good.

Comment: Please remember to check the correct answer when you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments in the comments, it sounds like a one time code invitation to register would be a good solution. You will need to decide how much information is good to populate in the forms for your audience.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. One way is to allow user to provide an email and some details to request an invite. Another - to send user an invite vie email that you already have.

This can be achieved by creating an invitation record in your database that will be deleted once the account has been created.